# Can I process React-components by taking them in with document.getElementsByClassName()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm kind of just getting started with React, and I want to create a pathfinding-visualizer. I've already made many pathfinding-algorithms in Python, so I know how they work. The thing I'm struggling with in React, is how to use the components to be able to visualize what nodes are being searched and which ones are being queued etc. What I've tried so far, is simply creating a grid by nesting components in each other:

```
    export class GridNode extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                flex:this.props.size,
                border:"1px solid black",
                width:"20px",
                height: "20px",
                color: "white"
            }
        }
    render() {
        return (
        <div 
        style={this.state}
        className="Node"
        index_x={this.props.index_x}
        index_y={this.props.index_y}
        isStart={this.props.isStart}
        isGoal={this.props.isGoal}
        iswall={this.props.isWall}
        onClick={GridNode.changeStartNode(this)}
        handlehighlight={this.changeStartNode}>
        </div>
        )
    }
}


    export class Row extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            numOfColumns:57,
            index_y: this.props.index_y
        };
    }

    render() {
        let columns = [];
        for (let index_x = 0; index_x < this.state.numOfColumns; index_x++) {
            columns.push(<GridNode index_x={index_x} index_y={this.props.index_y}></GridNode>);
        } 
        return <div className="Row" style={{display:"flex"}}>{columns}</div>;
    }
}

export class Grid extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            numOfRows: 23
        }
    }
    render() {
        let rows = [];
        for (let index_y = 0; index_y < this.state.numOfRows; index_y++) {
            rows.push(<Row index_y={index_y}></Row>)
        }
        return <div className="Grid" >{rows}</div>
    }
}
```

So my idea was to have a separate script/separate files that deal with the main part of the pathfinding-algorithms, and simply extracting the nodes from the grid and access them from a matrix like so:

```
export const testFunction = () => {
    let nodes = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("Node"));
    let matrix = [];
    let reference = nodes[0].getAttribute("index_y");
    let chunkSize = 0;
    for (let node of nodes) {
      if (node.getAttribute("index_y") !== reference) {
        break;
      }
      chunkSize++;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i+=chunkSize) {
      matrix.push(nodes.slice(i, i+chunkSize));
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

where I'm just creating an array of arrays. So my idea was to use this matrix and access each node individually, and perform calculations according to their values (i.e. props and state). However, I cannot access this information (or at least to my knowledge; as I said I'm new to this) directly when using the document.getElements... function, because this only gives me access to the values defined in the HTML-tag. So I guess my question is: how do I interact with these components? Do I need to make another class that extends react.component which takes in Grid and thereby can get access to the other elements' methods? Or is there a more suitable approach to this project? I think I'm confusing myself a lot hehe. My main problem is that I cannot access the states/props of the nodes that I want to process when doing what I'm trying now

Comment: It is possible to select elements directly in the DOM, but doesn't seem like its necessary or a good approach for your stated goals. Querying the DOM needs to happen after the component has been mounted to the DOM. It would be helpful to have more context about how and when the `testFunction` will be called.

Comment: My recommendation is to keep state in one component. Then use props to components that merely represent the state. This frees you from needing access to the nodes at all. Simply add a type prop and props for handling any events to the nodes. This way, only a container for the grid needs to be stateful and manage updating the state of the grid. See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and [Composition vs Inherteance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) See if [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/accessing-dom?file=src/App.js) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is bit complicated to replicate it and write final solution, but generating any grid uses `yourDataArray.map(a => (<td>{a}</td>))` logic. So the main point is to store your grid data in some state, that can be Array of Arrays or Array of Objects, e.g. this one:

```
[
  ["one-one", "one-two", "one-three"],
  ["two-one", "two-two", "two-three"],
  ["three-one", "three-two", "three-three"]
]
```

If you know the "coordinates" of your data, you can simply change / update them.

The Array of Arrays you can use for creating grid this way:

```
const Grid = ({data}) => (
  <table>
  <tbody>
    {data.map((row, i) => (
      <tr key={i}>
        {row.map((cell, ix) => (
          <td key={ix}>{cell}</td>
        ))}
      </tr>
    ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
)
```

It's up to you, how you store and use your grid data. Working example, including the way you can change your state of different fields in grid, is here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-thunder-63io7